# Angular 6 - angular-notifier

Tags: angular6

I am using [angular-notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-notifier) for notifications. But I can't seem to find any support for custom HTML. When I append any html tag to the message to be displayed in toast, the html tag too renders in the message. Let me know if any one has the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to customize the notifier using ng-template. First define a custom ng-template in your component HTML:

```
<ng-template #customNotification let-notificationData="notification">
    <my-custom-alert type="notificationData.type">
        {{ notificationData.message }}
        // Here you can define any custom HTML
    </my-custom-alert>
</ng-template>
```

After, Inside your component, you can then reference the ng-template using template variable #customNotification using Angular's ViewChild:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
...
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
@ViewChild('customNotification') customNotificationTmpl;
...
constructor(private notifierService: NotifierService) {}

showNotification() {
   const msg = {
       message: 'Hi there!',
       type: 'info'
   };

   this.notifier.show({
       message: msg.message,
       type: msg.type,
       template: this.customNotificationTmpl
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes, we can customize the notifier using ng-template. But I am getting response from my webservice in HTML format. Every response is different. There is fix HTM Lstructure.

Comment: Can you show some code example?  I don't understand what's the problem. The HTML response from web service may not embed into ng-template?

Comment: I have reached a similar problem - I even cannot add a new line:

this.notifier.notify('error', 'Multiline <br/> message ' +"\n" + 'here will show as a single line' ...

I have go through this the last half an hour and still found only that topic. I am not sure that the only way of adding a new line, or just a simple <b> tag should be a whole template?

Comment: Well guys, here is the decision:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53065215/new-line-in-angular-notifier

We just put the content in the [innerHTML] attribute.

```<span [innerHTML]="notificationData.message"></span>```

Comment: I have noticed that Angular is stripping out code that its thinks suspect when inserting html. For instance adding a <strong> or <i> is fine but try add an anchor with classes.

Comment: I was able to use routerLink in my notification template from this answer:
{{ notificationData.message }}
      <a [routerLink]="['/agents', { data: agent }]" style="color: #009A44;">{{ username }}</a>

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way in the documentation
[angular-notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-notifier)

You can define a custom ng-template as follows in yout component.html file:

```
<notifier-container>
  <ng-template #customNotification let-notificationData="notification">
    <span type="notificationData.type">
      <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z" fill="#1976d2"/>
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
      </svg>
      <span>{{ notificationData.message }} to angular-notifier</span>
    </span>
  </ng-template>
</notifier-container>
```

Inside your component, you can then reference the  by its template variable #customNotification using Angular's ViewChild:

```
import { ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
 
@Component({
    // ...
})
export class SomeComponent {
    @ViewChild("customNotification", { static: true }) customNotificationTmpl;
 
    constructor(private notifierService: NotifierService) {}
 
    showNotification() {
        this.notifier.show({
            message: "Hi there!",
            type: "info",
            template: this.customNotificationTmpl
        });
    }
}
```