# New line in Angular Notifier

Tags: angular, notifications, angular6, newline, multiline

As I cannot find a decision for this, here is a simple question for Angular 6. I am using `angular 6` with `angular-notofier` service and I am trying to show a simple multiline message for the user.

I have tried using HTML tags `<br/>` and New line chars `"\n"` but with no success. Looks like there is string escaping against `XSS` or something and I cannot add a new line.

Any ideas if I can do it that way OR if I am trying to do it in the wrong way (if so, then why is it wrong and how am I supposed to do it?)?

I would like to avoid more complicated constructions like custom templates (despite I suspect the problem should be presented there also).

Here is my "code":

```
constructor(
  private notifier: NotifierService,
```

...

```
this.notifier.notify(
  'error', 
  'Multiline' + "\n" + ' message will <br/> print in one line...' ....
```

Thanks a lot!
Anton

Comment: if you use `` it will be interpreted as HTML, so you can do `\`Multiline <br/> message will <br/> print 3 line`\`

Comment: Unfortunately not, @Alann. I see it exactly the same way :(

Comment: Even with the backquote @Anton Mitsev :( ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you want to pass your customized message then you can leverage the template. Through template you can have complete control how a message should be displayed.

### in html

yes, you need to use template in html to have custom message including multi line.

```
<ng-template #notification let-notificationData="notification">
       <span [innerHTML]="notificationData.message"></span>
</ng-template>
```

### in ts

```
 @ViewChild('notification') notificationTemplate;

 this.notifier.show({
           message: msg.message,
           type: msg.messageType,
           template: this.notificationTemplate //<-- template name from html.
        });
```

For more details look at official docs - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-notifier

Comment: Small extension: In order to add the possibility to write `<br>` and render it, modify `{{ notificationData.message }}` to `<span [innerHTML]="notificationData.message"></span>`. This should result in a new line as expected.

Comment: Thanks guys, that worked! Only thing that is missing now is my X button, which disappeared somewhere :) I keep trying...

Comment: @AntonMitsev I had the same issue with the X button and I started to dig into the library's code. However, for some reason I could not find what exactly the code do when there is a custom html template. Then, I just decided to create own X button (copied the one from the library). In an answer you will see my code.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new custom template, the library uses only your html. Thus, writing a custom button is required (probably that will be changed somehow in the future, but now that is a solution).

**In HTML:**

```html
<button
    class="notifier__notification-button"
    type="button"
    title="dismiss"
    (click)="onClickDismiss()"
>
    <svg class="notifier__notification-button-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="20" height="20">
      <path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z" />
    </svg>
</button>
```

**Then, the following in the TS:**

```js
onClickDismiss() {
   this.notifierService.hide(this.notificationId);
}
```